# How does the Authorization server validates the client_secret in Oauth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

In the context of OAuth2.0, After the RO (Resource Owner) approves the consent (clicks on the "Allow") - the AS (Authorization Server) will redirect the client to the redirect_uri passed by the client and add query params e.g. (the code and the state):

```
https://example-app.com/redirect?code=<the auth code>&state=<state>
```

Then the client should exchange (sends these to the AS) the: `authorization_code + client_id + client_secret` for an **Access token**

Okta defines the client_secret [as such](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type):

> client_secret - The application’s client secret. This ensures that the
> request to get the access token is made only from the application, and
> not from a potential attacker that may have intercepted the
> authorization code

BUT **how on earth the Authorization Server knows how to validate this `client_secret` which the client have created ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client did not create client secret. When you create new client on Authorization server, Authorization server generates client secret (if type of client is confidential, public client does not have secret). You get client_id and client_secret from Authorization server and use it in your client.

Comment: OK, So in case of public client, how does AS verifies that client is trusted? if public client not sends client_secret

Comment: You need an access token to access the resources, so user has to log in. I am not sure what kind of verification do you expect. Public clients are less secure than confidential ones.

Comment: You should use PKCE to prevent hacker who intercepted authorization code to get the tokens.